# Assigning a collection to be a more derived type based on value passed in

Tags: c#

Say I have a class:

```
    public class Farm
{
  IList<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
  public Farm(string type)
  {
      if (type == "Walrus")
          Animals = new List<Walrus>();
      if (type == "Giraffe")
          Animals = new List<Giraffe>();
  }
}
```

And there are two types of animals:

```
    public class Animal
    {

    }

    public class Walrus : Animal
    {

    }

    public class Giraffe : Animal
    {

    }
```

And say a farm can only farm either Walrus or Giraffes. How can the code be made so that if "Walrus" is passed to the Farm constructor the IList becomes a List of Walrus butif "Giraffes" is passed the IList becomes a list of Giraffes List.

so the above doesn't work. Does anyone know how this could be implemented

Comment: For the list of Animal, what are you gonna do with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are probably looking for [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x6a29h6.aspx):

```
public class Farm<T> where T: Animal
{
   public IList<T> Animals { get; set; }
   public Farm()
   {
      Animals = new List<T>();    
   }
}
```

Above would allow you to create a specialized `Farm` instance, e.g.

```
var giraffeFarm = new Farm<Giraffe>();
```

At the same time you can use a [constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) to enforce that your type `T` is derived from `Animal`